# Post build event triggers error MSB3073 exited with code 9009

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

I have something like this as a post build event

```
"$(SDK40ToolsPath)sgen.exe"
```

When the build runs on a new build machine, I get this error

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(4291,5): error MSB3073: The command ""sgen.exe" ..." exited with code 9009.
```

Which means command not found.
The sgen.exe is located in these folders

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\x64\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\
```

I have VS2015 installed, Microsoft Build Tools 2015.

How can I specify the right path to the sgen.exe?

Comment: Please try use MSBuild.exe from the path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin". Starting with Visual Studio 2013, the 2013 version of MSBuild will ship as a part of Visual Studio instead of the .NET Framework. You can use the command "echo "$(SDK40ToolsPath)"" to check which path been used.

Comment: I have modified in TFSbuild.proj to have ToolsVersion 14
<Project DefaultTargets="MakeRelease" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="14.0">

Comment: What is result when you build the project with Visual Studio not TFS? It seems that you have set the MSBuild location with a old path on TFS, you can try to build the project with MSBuild version 14.0 on TFS. personally， this issue should not related to the path of the sgen.exe, you can use the absolute path instead.

Comment: Well, locally it works fine (I trigger the build from VS and TFSbuild.proj is not used). And before the *.proj file had and old reference to ToolsVersion 4 and it did not work. Now I switched to 14 and it works fine.

Comment: Glad to know it works to you. You can convert your comment to the answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified in TFSbuild.proj to have ToolsVersion 14